# d3: Coloring Multiple Lines from Nested Data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently assembling some line graphs with circles at the datapoints from arrays of JSON objects formatted like so:

```
var data = [{
    "name": "metric1",
    "datapoints": [
        [10.0, 1333519140],
        [48.0, 1333519200]
    ]
}, {
    "name": "metric2",
    "datapoints": [
        [48.0, 1333519200],
        [12.0, 1333519260]
    ]
}]
```

I want to have a color for each metric, so I'm trying to color them based on the index of
the object within the array data.  The code I have currently for just placing the circles looks like:

```
// We bind an svg group to each metric.
var metric_groups = this.vis.selectAll("g.metric_group")
  .data(data).enter()
  .append("g")
    .attr("class", "metric_group");

// Then bind a circle for each datapoint.
var circles = metric_groups.selectAll("circle")
.data(function(d) { return d.datapoints; });

circles.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 3.5);
```

Now if I change that last bit to something like:

```
circles.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 3.5);
  .style("fill", function(d,i) { return i%2 ? "red" : "blue"; }
```

I get alternating red and blue circles, as could be expected.
Taking some advice from [Nested Selections : 'Nesting and Index'](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/#index), I tried:

```
circles.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 3.5);
  .style("fill", function(d,i,j) { return j%2 ? "red" : "blue"; }
```

Which doesn't work (j is undefined), presumably because we are in the named property datapoints, rather than an array element.  How might I go about doing the coloring that I want without changing my data structure?  Thanks!

Comment: I fixed the issue by setting the style on the groups instead of the circles (why did it take me posting on stack overflow to think of that?).  I'd still appreciate a less work-around-y answer, (e.g. for the case where the circles and paths within a group would want different styles, or the property of the child is something that cannot be inherited for whatever reason).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do here is to have the circles inherit a fill style from the parent G element:

```
var color = d3.scale.category20();

var metricGroup = vis.selectAll(".metric-group")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "metric-group")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

var circle = metricGroup.selectAll("circle")
    .data(function(d) { return d.datapoints; })
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 3.5);
```

If you defined categorical colors as CSS classes, you could also use a dynamic class name and inherit that way:

```
var metricGroup = vis.selectAll(".metric-group")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "metric-group " + color(d.name); });
```

With corresponding CSS:

```
.metric1 circle { fill: red; }
.metric2 circle { fill: blue; }
```

Another approach is to use [each](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-each) to access the parent data:

```
metricGroup.each(function(p, j) {
  d3.select(this).selectAll("circle")
      .data(p.datapoints)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .style("fill", color(p.name));
});
```

I also think using the group index `j` would work; I'm not sure why it's undefined for you, but there is a spurious semicolon in your code example (in `.attr("r", 3.5);`), so it's possible there's something else going on. At any rate, it's more idiomatic to derive categorical colors from data rather than group index, so I'd use one of the above techniques.

Answer (score 1):

In one of my visualizations I had the same problem. My solution was the following (adapted to your example):

```
var count = 0;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var metric_groups = this.vis.selectAll("g.metric_group")
  .data(data).enter()
  .append("g")
    .attr("class", "metric_group");

var circles = metric_groups.selectAll("circle")
  .data(function(d) {return d.datapoints;});

circles.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 3.5)
  .style("fill", function(d,i){
    d.number = count;
    count++;
    return color(d.number);
  });
```

The key is to give each datum a unique attribute which can be used to give the corresponding element a unique color across different groups.

I hope this helps or supports you in finding a similar solution!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!  Sorry if I'm misunderstanding this, but this code looks like it will assign a unique color to every circle, which is kind of solving a different problem.  My issue is wanting each circle in the same line to have the same color.  It seems like I could possibly come up with something similar, but I was wondering if there was a more idiomatic way.

Comment: Ah, now I see where the problem is! I will think about it!

Comment: A different aproach is to use a for-loop: Iterate over the metrics and draw each graph and the corresponding circles inside the loop. Doing so is not very pretty but it does work.